# Error Running Python Script from Batch File FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '[]'

Tags: python

When I try to run my batch file for python script I get the error

```
D:\Sandbox\Python\Python Scripts>AQACompareBooks.py "D:/Sandbox/AQA/OrderAnalysis/Customer 1 OrderAnalysis -1 2018-05-08.xlsx"
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sandbox\Python\Python Scripts\AQACompareBooks.py", line 33, in <module>
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
  File "D:\Dev\Sandbox\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(io)
  File "D:\Dev\Sandbox\Python\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 116, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '[]'
```

Batch File

```
AQACompareBooks.py "D:\Sandbox\AQA\OrderAnalysis\Customer1 OrderAnalysis -1 2018-05-08.xlsx"
```

Python Code

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  
import os
import sys


print(sys.argv[1:])
file = format(sys.argv[1:])
xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
```

If I set the path manually in the code I everything works fine.

i.e.

```
file = 'D:\Sandbox\AQA\OrderAnalysis\Customer1 OrderAnalysis -1 2018-05-08.xlsx'
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before?

Batch file and script are in the same folder. 
The files I want to load is not

Comment: Does the print show anything? What line has the fail?

Comment: The code you show doesn't produce that error. We need to see the part that is broken to offer suggestions.

Comment: The print doesn't show anything.

Comment: To my knowledge that code has to produce the error. If remove the argument in the batch file, and set the path manually in the script. i.e. file = 'path' everything works ok.

Comment: I guess you are call it wrong. try to call python AQACompareBooks.py "D:\Sandbox\AQA\OrderAnalysis\Customer1 OrderAnalysis -1 2018-05-08.xlsx"

It's works fine. So, you are calling it wrong

Comment: You should use the [raw string prefix `r`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-stringprefix) if you're going to have unescaped backslashes in your string literals. I also don't know why you seem to have lost the argument, but `argv[1:]` is still a list (slice with 0 or more elements), so those `[]` characters may come from the `format` call. The exception you showed comes from code we don't know.

Comment: @tdelaney Sorry. I added the line where the code breaks. xls=pd.ExcelFile(file).

It looks like sys.argv[1:] is returning []

Comment: Part of the problem is that it should be `file = sys.argv[1]` but that will raise an error because apparantly you have no `argv[1]`. Try `print(sys.argv)` (the whole arg list) and see if you filename is in position zero. Then this will be a question of how your batch file called python. Was it just the line you post or was it run in `FORFILES` or `CMD`?

Comment: If I try file = sys.argv[1] I get list index out of range.
If I do  sys.argv[0:] I get OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "['D:\\\\Sandbox\\\\Python\\\\Python Scripts\\\\AQACompareBooks.py']" All of this was run in CMD

Comment: That index out of range is because the argument was already missing. Making it not an error broke your Python program, but the original problem is outside of it.

Comment: @YannVernier Apologies but I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean this is a Windows file type association problem, not a Python problem. Changing the Python code in response just created a layered second error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like it's a Windows issue with the extension association for `.py` files. In one Windows installation I checked where a test Python script did receive arguments, the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\Shell\open\command` is set to `"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*` (including those quotes). The trailing `%*` is what passes the arguments that Python then stores in `sys.argv`.

Second is the part with `format(sys.argv[1:])`; that slice will always produce a list, whereas the filename you wanted is stored in the single element `sys.argv[1]`. Simply use that instead.

With thanks to tdelaney for pointing them out, the associations can be checked (and, if administrator, set) using the `assoc` and `ftype` commands:

```
C:\Users\yann>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

C:\Users\yann>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" "%L" %*
```

Comment: Hi Yann, thanks for the answer. How would I check this. Also with the computer that I am using, python is installed on the D drive and not the C where the OS is installed.

Comment: Try the registry editor `regedit` (note that the registry holds a lot of other things, including more critical settings, so don't edit it carelessly).

Comment: On the command line `ftype Python.File` should show the file association.

Comment: Then check `assoc .py` to find what the association you do have is called. It appears your Python installation wasn't made by the usual installer and may be missing the feature that lets it pass arguments.

Comment: I reinstalled python, and was able to receive the results in above in your example using the commands in cmd. Still the batch fails though.

Comment: At this point you *might* have a different problem. What output do you get if you put something like `import sys ; print(repr(sys.argv))` early in the Python script?

Comment: The output that I get for print(repr(sys.argv))  is ['D:/Sandbox/Python/Python Scripts/AQACompareBooks.py']

Comment: So it's still not getting its argument. Does the `assoc` command also match? You might have two distinct options for opening .py files now, one of which doesn't pass arguments.

Comment: So I stripped python and all editors from the machine, reinstalled everything and it worked. I guess it was a pathing issue. Thanks for the help everyone!